# How can I check if a Flutter application is running in debug?

Tags: flutter, debugging, dart, flutter-run, flutter-debug

I'm looking for a way to execute code in Flutter when the app is in Debug mode. Is that possible in Flutter? I can't seem to find it anywhere in the documentation.

Something like this

```
If(app.inDebugMode) {
   print("Print only in debug mode");
}
```

How can I check if the Flutter application is running in debug or release mode?

Comment: [Check Flutter mode from Dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11392)

Comment: I tried assert(() { print("Debug mode"); return true; }); but that just gives me an error that can't compile. The "Profile" they are talking about later in the post doesn't make much sense to me. Can you please explain how to use it ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

While this works, using constants `kReleaseMode` or `kDebugMode` is preferable. See [Rémi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707028/check-if-running-app-is-in-debug-mode/49707787#answer-55612795) below for a full explanation, which should probably be the accepted question.

---

The easiest way is to use *assert* as it only runs in debug mode.

Here's an example from Flutter's Navigator source code:

```
assert(() {
  if (navigator == null && !nullOk) {
    throw new FlutterError(
      'Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.\n'
      'The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a '
      'widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.'
    );
  }
  return true;
}());
```

Note in particular the `()` at the end of the call - *assert* can only operate on a Boolean, so just passing in a function doesn't work.

Comment: The "Note in particular" was the part that my IDE was tripping over. Thank you so much!

Comment: When you write `() { .... }` you're defining the function, but not calling it. Adding the `()` actually calls the function.

Comment: This seems a lot more semantically correct than checking the kdebugmode const.

Answer (score 601):

In later versions, you can use `kDebugMode`:

```dart
if (kDebugMode)
  doSomething();
```

---

While asserts can technically be used to manually create an "is debug mode" variable, you should avoid that.

Instead, use the constant `kReleaseMode` from `package:flutter/foundation.dart`

---

The difference is all about tree shaking.

Tree shaking (aka the compiler removing unused code) depends on variables being constants.

The issue is, with asserts our `isInReleaseMode` boolean is **not** a constant. So when shipping our app, both the dev and release code are included.

On the other hand, `kReleaseMode` **is** a constant. Therefore the compiler is correctly able to remove unused code, and we can safely do:

```
if (kReleaseMode) {

} else {
  // Will be tree-shaked on release builds.
}
```

Comment: Just a small side note as well, to avoid pollution your class with unknowns import like following ```import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' as Foundation;``` then you can do ```Foundation. kReleaseMode```

Comment: How is this so far down, this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Also there is  `kDebugMode`

Comment: Will tree shaking also occur with widgets? So if I did a Visibility widget with visible: kDebugMode will that widget be removed by the compiler for release builds?

Comment: Can we also know if the .apk is signed with `signingConfigs.debug` with the same constant?

Comment: upvoted - but jus a note - @AlexanderSkvortsov mentioned kDebugMode (als upvoted).
kDebugMode has the advantage of  cleaning out your debug code while profiling (kReleaseMode is afaik false when profiling so !kReleaseMod is inferior to kDebugMode)

Comment: Another trick to avoid symbol pollution as @Oliver noted is to use the [`show`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility) command to import just the symbol(s) you want to use, i.e. `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kDebugMode;`

Answer (score 105):

Here is a simple solution to this:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

Then you can use `kReleaseMode` like

```
if(kReleaseMode){ // Is Release Mode??
    print('release mode');
} else {
    print('debug mode');
}
```

Comment: if you need code for release - use kReleaseMode... the else bit is either debug or profiling...
use kDebugMode for debug and kProfileMode as needed

Answer (score 71):

## [`kDebugMode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kDebugMode-constant.html)

You can now use the [`kDebugMode` constant](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kDebugMode-constant.html).

```dart
if (kDebugMode) {
  // Code here will only be included in debug mode.
  // As kDebugMode is a constant, the tree shaker
  // will remove the code entirely from compiled code.
} else {

}
```

This is preferable over `!kReleaseMode` as it also checks for profile mode, i.e., `kDebugMode` means *not in **release** mode **and** not in **profile** mode*.

### [`kReleaseMode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kReleaseMode-constant.html)

If you just want to check for *release mode* and not for profile mode, you can use `kReleaseMode` instead:

```dart
if (kReleaseMode) {
  // Code here will only be run in release mode.
  // As kReleaseMode is a constant, the tree shaker
  // will remove the code entirely from other builds.
} else {

}
```

### [`kProfileMode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kProfileMode-constant.html)

If you just want to check for *profile mode* and not for release mode, you can use `kProfileMode` instead:

```dart
if (kProfileMode) {
  // Code here will only be run in release mode.
  // As kProfileMode is a constant, the tree shaker
  // will remove the code entirely from other builds.
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 69):

Please use [Remi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707028/how-can-i-check-if-a-flutter-application-is-running-in-debug/55612795#55612795) with `kReleaseMode` and `kDebugMode` or Dart compilation won't be able to tree-shake your code.

---

This little snippet should do what you need:

```
bool get isInDebugMode {
  bool inDebugMode = false;
  assert(inDebugMode = true);
  return inDebugMode;
}
```

If not, you can configure your IDE to launch a different `main.dart` in debug mode where you can set a Boolean.

Comment: I put it as static in an `Application` class so I can write `Application.isInDebugMode` where I need it.

Comment: this is called in release. use constants kDebugMode

Answer (score 29):

Not to be picky, but the foundation package includes a `kDebugMode` constant.

So:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' as Foundation;

if(Foundation.kDebugMode) {
   print("App in debug mode");
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I believe the latest way to do this is:

```
const bool prod = const bool.fromEnvironment('dart.vm.product');
```

[src](https://twitter.com/flutterdev/status/1048278525432791041?lang=en)

Comment: Re *"the latest way"*: Can you add some version/date information?

Comment: As of Dart 2.9.0, this is not recommended, see [do_not_use_environment](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/do_not_use_environment): "Using values derived from the environment at compile-time, creates hidden global state and makes applications hard to understand and maintain."

Comment: It strikes me that the assert() is the best way. No need to remember arbitrary const names. assert is documented to trigger in debug mode. Now, there may be fuzzy issues between debug and production but the OP was asking for how to detect if in debug mode.

Answer (score 5):

**Just import this**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' 


String bulid = kReleaseMode ? "Release" : "";

or

String bulid = kDebugMode ? "Debug" : "";

or

String bulid = kProfileMode ? "Profile" : "";
```

**Or try this**

```
if (kDebugMode) {
   print("Debug");
} else if (kReleaseMode) {
    print("Release"); 
} else if (kProfileMode) {
  print("Profile"); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've created this useful class, based on other answers and inspired on Android usage.
If anything changes on "Foundation" package, it would not be necessary to change the entire application, it would be necessary to change only this class.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' as Foundation;

abstract class Build {

    static const bool isDebugMode = Foundation.kDebugMode;

    static const bool isReleaseMode = Foundation.kReleaseMode;

    static const bool isWeb = Foundation.kIsWeb;

    static const bool isProfileMode = Foundation.kProfileMode;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a file named *constants.dart*. Add these variables in it:

```
const bool kReleaseMode = bool.fromEnvironment('dart.vm.product');
const bool kProfileMode = bool.fromEnvironment('dart.vm.profile');
const bool kDebugMode = !kReleaseMode && !kProfileMode;

printk(String string) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print(string);
  }
}
```

Then import this constant file in any other file and use it like this:

```
    import 'package:package_name/constants.dart';

    if(kDebugMode){
        //Debug code
    }else{
        //Non-Debug code
    }

    printk("Debug Log");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use flutter's [foundation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/foundation-library.html) library. You can get `debug`, `profile` and `release`

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

then

```
if (kDebugMode) {
  // debug code
}

if (kProfileMode) {
 // profile code
}

if (kReleaseMode) {
    // release code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from Dart [Documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert):

> When exactly do assertions work? That depends on the tools and
>   framework you’re using:
>
> - Flutter enables assertions in **debug** mode.
> - Development-only tools such as dartdevc typically enable assertions by default.
> - Some tools, such as dart and dart2js, support assertions through a command-line flag:    --enable-asserts.
>
> In **production** code, **assertions are ignored**, and the arguments to
>   assert aren’t evaluated.

Comment: How does that answer the question? It is *"How can I check if the Flutter application is running in debug or release mode?"* Can you summarise in your own words?

Answer (score 0):

In flutter you can use “foundations” package to check is the app debug or release by using the following constants:

- kReleaseMode
- kProfileMode
- kDebugMode

**

### Here is an example:

**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

modeFinder() {
  String currentMode;

  if (kDebugMode) {
       currentMode = "Debug mode"
  } else if (kReleaseMode) {
       currentMode = "Release mode"
  } else {
       currentMode = "Profile mode"
  }

  print(string);
}
```