# How to differentiate between debug and release mode in flutter in code?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to have some functionality only in release mode, and not in debug. It's longer to get past it and just commenting it during development is not a good idea. As there is always a probability of forgetting about it when making release builds.

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#debug-mode-assertions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By importing `flutter/foundation.dart`, a top level constant is available for this check:

[kReleaseMode](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/kReleaseMode-constant.html)

This is better than asserts, because it works with tree shaking.

Comment: What do you mean by tree shaking?

Comment: The compiler will remove unused code. So if you're doing `if (kReleaseMode) {} else {}` then the compiler knows that the `else` will never be executed, and therefore remove it.

Answer (score 4):

This worked well for me.
Declare a function like following;

```
bool get isInDebugMode {
  bool inDebugMode = false;
  assert(inDebugMode = true);
  return inDebugMode;
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
if(isInDebugMode) {
    print('Debug');
} else {
    print('Release');
}
```

[Source of information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49709147/6805835)

========================================================================
You can also use [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55606816/6805835) given by @Rémi Rousselet:

First import the package:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

and use `kReleaseMode` like this:

```
if(kReleaseMode) { // is in Release Mode ?
    print('Release');
} else {
    print('Debug');
}
```