# How can I export high resolution image of the screen in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, export

how can I export the screen as an image or PDF in Flutter in high resolution? Is it possible to export the container with background image and textfield with user input as image? I tried this solution ([How to take a screenshot of the current widget - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117958/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-current-widget-flutter)), but the resolution is to bad. I need the screen in different size e.g. 40x60cm, 20x30cm and 300Ddpi.

Comment: What you want to do is not simple... The method you linked "take" the rendered widget and "put" it in a variable. You can't take a widget and export with a bigger size

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Is there any other way to export the widget as image? I read flutter is supporting .svg files, so maybe when I add .svg files instead of jpg files?

Comment: It should return a png, not a jpg. And btw no, as much I know, you can't export as svg

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to use `pixelRatio`?

```
ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 10);
```

Comment: I will try it now, and let you know.

Comment: Thank you! it take a bit more time but the result is way better.

Comment: @Max You will try it now, and let me know when? ;-)

Comment: @Thierry thanks, this fixed my low-res issues.

Answer (score 0):

Tried out `pixelRatio` and combined it with larger resp. no `cacheWidth` - it works indeed, at least for PNG export.

Be aware however, that a `pixelRatio` of 10 takes quite some time to capture...

Code Snippet for image:

```
child: ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
  child: Image.file(
    File(widget.myGroup.picture),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    // NO cacheWidth:
    // cacheWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
  ),
),
```

Code Snippet for _capturePng():

```
Future<Uint8List> _capturePng() async {
  RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();

  if (boundary.debugNeedsPaint) {
    print("Waiting for boundary to be painted.");
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 20));
    return _capturePng();
  }

  var image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 10);
  var byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
  return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

(Referring to [this question here about screenshot with flutter on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645037/unable-to-take-screenshot-in-flutter))