# How to show a widget only in debug mode

Tags: flutter, dart

Supposer I have a `Text`, I want to only show it in debug mode. In release mode, it's hidden.

Now I come out an idea that set it's text string to empty.

But what if it is a `Button`. How to show it only in debug mode?

In C#, I can use conditions like

```
#if DEBUG

#endif
```

Is there something alike in flutter?

Comment: Please check this out. it surely has the answer for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707028/check-if-running-app-is-in-debug-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show or hide a Widget by testing if kReleaseMode is false or not. So if you want to show a Widget if debug mode is on then do the following:

```
body: kReleaseMode == false ? 'Widget at Debug mode' : 'Widget at Release mode'
```

Comment: Should we keep the code that way or should we remove it before release? I mean does it adds up in the output APK?