# Change settings if debugging - Flutter/Dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to change some settings if i'm locally developing the app, such as:

**settings.dart**

```
bool debug = true;

String serverUrl;

if (debug) {
  serverUrl = 'http://localhost'; 
} else {
  serverUrl = 'https://myserver.com';
}
```

And then, use it with:

**requests.dart**

```
import 'settings.dart';

void fetchApi async () {
  response = http.get(serverUrl);

  // do some stuff
}
```

But actually, I can't use the `if` function outside a function, the error says:

`Expected an identifier.dart(missing_identifier)`

Is there something that I can do to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55612795/9512964, hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, What you can do is define a getter for url as shown in this code:

```dart
String get serverUrl {
    If(kDebugMode) {
        return "https://myserver.com";
    } else {
        return "https://myserver.com";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about this feature